# How to insert "Topo North Arrow" using ArcObject

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, topography, north-arrow

[image]Does anyone know how to insert "Topo NorthArrow" using ArcObject C# SDK? There is no example or snippet. I am not sure if it is even available through SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I googled "arcobjects add north arrow". The very first search result is a C# snippet:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000004w000000

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the same Declination. There are 2 North Arrow from production mapping. One I am looking for is "Topo - Topo North Arrow" which is different from snippet